# When to use indexed variables

Tags: variable-definitions, indexed-variable

Still learning the fundamentals of the language I would like to ask you what advantages there might be in writing something like:

```
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 4;
a[3] = "x";
```

It seems to me that it is always better to write

```
a = {2, 4, "x"};
```

Do you know about any practical constructs where indexed variables would offer an advantage?

Comment: Check [this](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/lichtblau/Lichtblau_Algorithms.nb) out, particularly the part on sparse arrays

Comment: Indexed variables can be used as dictionary table. So anywhere you might need a dictionary table, they are useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: see http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/lichtblau/

Comment: @Nasser, you were too slow to post the last link

Comment: @Rojo I am getting old

Comment: ... and I am already reading it, and thank both of you :)

Comment: Indexed variables can be used symbolically.  You can `Solve[a[1]^2==2, a[1]]` but you can't `Solve[a[[1]]^2==2, a[[1]] ]`.  This is what we typically use when we don't know the number of symbolic variables we need beforehand.  I would sometimes define a 3 by 3 matrix with explicit symbolic elements as `Array[a, {3,3}]`.

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9440/7167)

Comment: @Szabolcs - Thanks, that was an easy to understand example. Since I regularly read your answers on all topics, I would like to ask you a favour: A couple of days ago another newbie asked an interesting question: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48518/fullsimplify-inconsistent/48523#48523). However, he never got an answer from you experts. Would you please have a short look on this question?

Comment: @Szabolcs - magic ! answer just arrived :)

Comment: @Szabolcs please consider expanding on your comment as an answer, even if CW.

Comment: @Verbeia You're right, I should be better about this ... done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indexed variables can be used in symbolic calculations.  They're useful when the number of variables used needs to be changed programmatically.

Here's an example:

```
vars = Array[a, 3]
(* {a[1], a[2], a[3]} *)

Minimize[vars.vars, vars]
(* {0, {a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 0}} *)
```

They can also be used to emulate sparse arrays, as described [here](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/lichtblau/).