# Alternatives to indexed variables in Compile

Tags: function-construction, compile

According to the excellent answer given here by @Leonid Shifrin: [How to compile effectively?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively?answertab=votes#tab-top),

> You can not really use indexed variables in `Compile`, although it may appear that you can.

Separately, 
@Szabolcs writes in [When to use indexed variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48602/when-to-use-indexed-variables)

> Indexed variables can be used in symbolic calculations. They're useful when the number of variables used needs to be changed programmatically.

Back to me now - I've recently been learning about indexed variables and getting my head around them. Here I'm generating a formula programmatically. For a simple example, it's a sum of sines,

```
f[x]=a[1]*Sin[x + b[1]] + a[2]*Sin[x + b[2]] + ...
```

The number of terms in the function is variable, which is why I'm generating the function programmatically. To generate a function with two terms, I run

```
sinfunction[a_, b_] := a*Sin[x + b];
variables = {a[#], b[#]} & /@ Range[2];
Total[sinfunction @@@ variables]
**Out=a[1]*Sin[x + b[1]] + a[2]*Sin[x + b[2]]**
```

Once I've generated a formula with *n* terms, it stays that size, but I then call the function many times with different parameters, and I'm looking to see if `Compile` can offer me any advantage. I'd like to be able to compile my function and run various benchmarks to see what happens compared to an uncompiled case.

Obviously for small expressions such as this there probably isn't any benefit to compiling ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CompilingMathematicaExpressions.html)), but I'm using this as an exercise to improve my knowledge of Mathematica for the future!

This hardcoded effort is impractical and probably somewhat redundant:

```
complexformula = a[1]*Sin[x + b[1]] + a[2]*Sin[x + b[2]];
complexcompiledFunction = With[{function = complexformula}, 
    Compile[{{a[1], _Real}, {b[1], _Real}, {a[2], _Real}, {b[2], _Real}, {x, _Real}},
        function
    ]
];
complexcompiledFunction[2, 3, 1, 1, 5]
**Out=1.6993**
```

Are there any alternatives? Or do I need to rethink my approach altogether?

Comment: I'm not sure what Leonid means in that post, but indexed variable can actually be used in `Compile` to some degree, for example: `Needs["CompiledFunctionTools\`"]` and `Compile[x[1], Sin[x[1]]] // CompilePrint`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148189/1871

Comment: Ah, we used to discuss it here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183912/1871 I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cf = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{x, a, b},
    x = Last@data;
    a = data[[1 ;; -2 ;; 2]];
    b = data[[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]];
    a.Sin[b + x]
    ]
   ];
cf@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10000001] // Timing
```

> {0.374402, 2.10248*10^6}

Comment: That's the hint I needed - it works for my requirements at least, thanks @Chenminqi