# Using Indexed variables in Compile?

Tags: compile, indexed-variable

This follows a: [useful post about Compile from about 10 years ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51406/alternatives-to-indexed-variables-in-compile)

In that post there is a comment:

> You can not really use indexed variables in Compile, although it may appear that you can.

For example,

```
cf=Compile[{{p, _Real, 3}},Indexed[p, {1, 2, 3}] Indexed[p, {3, 2, 1}]]
```

will compile and work just fine.

```
With[{rr = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3, 3}]},
 {rr[[1, 2, 3]] rr[[3, 2, 1]], cf[rr]}
 ]
```

*I seem to remember, but cannot find*, a utility in `` Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"] `` that assists in using Indexed variables in `Compile`.

Does anyone know if such utility exists; if so what is it, and does it make extraction from a tensor more efficient?

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
?CompiledFunctionTools`*
```

doesn't show anything like what I am looking for.

Comment: I think "indexed" variables in that post referred to things like `p[1,2,3]`. Leonid Shifrin's original answer was from 2012, but `Indexed` was added to the language in 2014. And indeed, `Indexed` works just fine with `Compile`! No need to worry about it.

Comment: What do you gain by using `Indexed` here instead of `Part`?  Isn't `cf = Compile[{{p, _Real, 3}}, p[[1, 2, 3]] p[[3, 2, 1]]]` equivalent to your code?

Comment: Nothing gained. Except in my actual case, the code is very long and I generate it symbolically ahead of time.  If I use p[[1,2,3]] without p having a value, it generates a bunch of warning. The symbolic Indexed[p,{i,j,k}] is handy for the general case.

Comment: I'm not sure what Leonid means in that post, but indexed variable can actually be used in `Compile` to some degree, try e.g. : `Needs["CompiledFunctionTools\`"]` and `Compile[x[1], Sin[x[1]]] // CompilePrint`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148189/1871

Comment: I think the takeaway is that indexed variables play nice with Compile.  (I don’t know how to indicate that this question has been answered?).  I do wonder if CompilePrint is still needed—uniconizing the compiled function  shows the compilation instructions.

Comment: @CraigCarter It's OK to summarize the comments to a community wiki answer :) .

Comment: Ah, we used to discuss it here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183912/1871 I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll sum up what I've learned.

The approach of using Indexed variables like so:

```
cf=Compile[{{p, _Real, 3}},Indexed[p, {1, 2, 3}] Indexed[p, {3, 2, 1}]]
```

is fine and also efficient.

**Here is a usage scenario:**

Suppose there is a very large set of line segments and you wish to find all intersecting pairs. It needs to be fast.

Suppose you want to call the function like so:

```
segmentsIntersect[{{{x1B, y1B}, {x1E, y1E}}, {{x2B, y2B}, {x2E, y2E}}}]
```

where `{{{x1B, y1B}, {x1E, y1E}}, {{x2B, y2B}, {x2E, y2E}}}` is a list of two segments, each segment being a list of its endpoints and the function returns `True` if they intersect.

Compute the intersection condition by using a parametric form of the line segments:

I use [FormalP] here because I find it useful in the body of Compile or Function.

```
s1B = {x1B, y1B} = {Indexed[\[FormalP], {1, 1, 1}], 
    Indexed[\[FormalP], {1, 1, 2}]};
s1E = {x1E, y1E} = {Indexed[\[FormalP], {1, 2, 1}], 
    Indexed[\[FormalP], {1, 2, 2}]};
s2B = {x2B, y2B} = {Indexed[\[FormalP], {2, 1, 1}], 
    Indexed[\[FormalP], {2, 1, 2}]};
s2E = {x2E, y2E} = {Indexed[\[FormalP], {2, 2, 1}], 
    Indexed[\[FormalP], {2, 2, 2}]};

seg1 = s1B + v (s1E - s1B);
seg2 = s2B + u (s2E - s2B);
```

The condition for segment intersection is that the parameters `u` and `v` are both in [0,1].

```
sol = {{uSol, vSol}} = FullSimplify[
   SolveValues[Thread[seg1 ==  seg2] , {u, v}]

intersectionCondition = And @@ ((0 <= # <= 1) & /@ sol[[1]])
```

Then the symbolic condition can be used in Compile:

```
segmentsIntersect = Compile[{{\[FormalP], _Real, 3}}, Evaluate[intersectionCondition]]
```

`Evaluate` is needed here because `Compile` has the attribute `HoldAll`

For clarity, I've neglected failure modes where a determinant-divisor is zero and the segments are collinear.

This can also be improved by filtering with the condition that the bounding boxes of each segment intersect.

Compile is fairly efficient at recognizing terms that appear twice and writing code that computes them only once.  However, in this case, Compile misses the determinant-divisor.  The compiled code can be improved by by forcing the computation of the determinant once.

For a large set of segment pairs, it is useful to make the compiled function listable:

```
segmentsIntersect = 
 Compile[{{\[FormalP], _Real, 3}}, Evaluate[intersectionCondition],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

Then,

```
segmentPairs = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2, 2, 2}];
segmentsIntersect[segmentPairs]
```