# How to name a variable with the value of another variable?

Tags: variable-definitions, assignment, concatenation

A simple but very important (at least for me) question. 
In some languages for defining a variable, for example, we can do:

i=10

"d"&i=30

So I have defined the variable d10, and...

d10=30

That is to say... I've named a variable (d10) as as function of an other variable (i).

How can I do this in Mathematica?
Sorry if the title is bad.

Regards!

Comment: Try with `Symbol["name"]`: "refers to a symbol with the specified name."

Comment: Maybe there are shorter idioms for this, but one way is: `Evaluate[ToExpression["d"~~ToString[i]]] = 30`

Comment: I'm wondering if you want `x[i]`?  It's not exactly what you asked for; but if you don't know you can use `x[i]` as a variable, which represents `x[10]` when `i` is `10`, then you might not know to ask for it.

Comment: Daniel, your suggestion works very well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Luis Be aware that Daniel's simple suggestion will *not* allow reassignment.  (As I'm sure he knows.)  I again updated my answer to make clear that the method I gave does allow reassignments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I shall assume that you want a compact syntax to make this practical to use.
I shall choose `cs`, standing for compound symbol:

```
cs[x__] :=
  ToHeldExpression @ ToString @ Row @ {x} /.
    {_[s_Symbol] :> s, _ :> $Failed}

func_[a___, Unevaluated @ cs[x__], b___] ^:= 
  ToHeldExpression @ ToString @ Row @ {x} /.
    {_[s_Symbol] :> func[a, s, b], _ :> $Failed}
```

Test:

```
i = 10;
cs["d", i] = 30;

d10
```

> ```
> 30
> ```

Any expressions can be used so long as their evaluated forms concatenate to a valid Symbol name:

```
cs[Pi, d10, "x"] = 86;

Pi30x
```

> ```
> 86
> ```

Reassignment is possible:

```
cs[Pi, d10, "x"] = 99;

Pi30x
```

> ```
> 99
> ```

If an invalid Symbol name is produced by the concatenation `$Failed` is returned:

```
cs[5, "x"] = 30
```

> ```
> $Failed
> ```

(Symbol names cannot start with numbers.)

---

Recommended reading:

- [Assigning values to a list of variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)
- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)
- [How to 'merge' a list like FromDigits, but with a mixture of numbers and symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121)
- [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/121) (especially Kuba's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Despite the accepted excellent answer by  Mr.Wizard I think it is worth to point out that the standard idiomatic approach to the problem in *Mathematica* is to use [indexed variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html):

```
In[1]:= i = 10;
d[i] = 30;
Definition[d]
d[10] = 10;
Definition[d]
```

> ```
> Out[3]= d[10] = 30
>
> Out[5]= d[10] = 10
> ```

Comment: A brief, but related discussion: [When to use indexed variables](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48602/).  I know the advantages/disadvantages of indexed variables have been discussed here and there on the site, but I'm having trouble locating relevant q & a. (+1)

Comment: For what it's worth this is covered in the **A Better Alternative** section at the top of my answer to the first linked question in my answer above.